# Get original image url from base64 Image String using Python?

Tags: python, base64

Wondering can someone point me in the right direction on how to convert base64 image string to its original image URL.

My code is scraping top 5 news from google based on my search string.
Images are in one big massive base64 string. Images are printing ok on my outlook email (my code extract the news and send out an email in outlook) but when I forward that email on to different email account can't see any image but a message `The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed or deleted`. Just to check that, I copied the image from my outlook email and tried to paste on word document; all I can see is an empty box but no image.

any advice, please?

Comment: not an expert in mail domain, but i have faced this problem before, check whether you are having any issues with sender address or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. To test that I have used two different emails in the code. I can see the images in my email (note I am executing the code from my machine), the other email which is logged on another PC can't see those images at all.

Comment: can you share the code, along with screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a URL from those.  Those base64 encoded strings are fully embedded images.  You could base64 decode them and save it to a file or just take the base64 encoded string an attach it to another image tag like in the incoming email.

If you have some specific code I could be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have used the encoded string in my email but when I forward that email,  for some reason image seems to disappear. To test this I also modified the code to send the email to two different people, except mine rest others can't see the image at all in the email.

* just take the base64 encoded string an attach it to another image tag like in the incoming email.* - ```<td style="vertical-align:center"><img src= '''+newsImg+''' width=100 height=100 ></td>``` This is how I am passing the base64 string. Is that what you mean?